# How to programatically check phone is wifi capable?

Tags: android, wifi, driver

How can I programatically check phone is wifi capable?

I'm NOT talking about enabling/disabling wifi. I want to get the presence of a wifi hardware/driver

Comment: @Preet Sangha no, that is not related to my question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<strike>boolean hasWifi = PackageManager.hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_WIFI);</strike>

```
PackageManager p = ctx.getPackageManager();
boolean hasWifi = p.hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_WIFI);
```

Check the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html) for further hardware constants that you can test. `ctx` is a Context instance.

*Edit: Sniff, forgot the correct way to use it, fixed my example.*

Comment: PackageManager.FEATURE_WIFI is from API Level 8 on-wards,  any other way to check it on level 7?

Comment: I don't know one from the top of my head, but I never needed such a feature for myself. Maybe someone else knows more.

Answer (score 1):

```
    PackageManager manager = getPackageManager();
    FeatureInfo info[] = manager.getSystemAvailableFeatures();
    for(int i=0; i<info.length; i++){
        if(((info[i].name)!=null)&&(info[i].name).equals("android.hardware.wifi")){
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Support wifi", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

hope this will help you